# Install Python dependencies on another server using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, virtualenv, jenkins-pipeline

Hi is there a possibility to ssh to a server activate a virtual env and install requirements from my Jenkins Pipeline Project

I have tried this but does not seem to maintain my virtual env session

```
node {
    sh '''
    ssh server virtualenv myvenv
    ssh server source myvenv/bin/activate && which python " 
    '''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution you have to run it like this

```
ssh server "source myvenv/bin/activate; which python"
```